# Swift 5: How to save results of NSFetchRequest to File

Tags: swift, macos

I am new to programming in general and have started with Swift. I have a feeling what I'm attempting to do is a bit outside of my scope, but I've come so far so here's the ask:

I am adding a tracker to a program for macOS X I've already created. The end user inputs a number and hits "Add to tracker" which then takes that number, the timestamp from the button click and writes that to the appropriate entity in Core Data. Everything works perfectly, my NSTable displays the data and I my batch delete works, but I cannot for the life of me work out the best way to take the results from the NSFetchRequest and print them to a text file.

Here is the code for my fetch request that occurs when the "print" button is hit:

```
@IBAction func printTracker(_ sender: Any) {
            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["caseDate","caseNumber"]
            fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
            
            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                let resultsDict = results as! [[String:String]]

                
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }     
    }
```

After the "resultsDict" declaration is where I just can't seem to come to a workable solution for getting it to string, then to txt file.

If I add a print command to the console as is, I can see that resultsDict pulls correctly with the following format:

`[["caseNumber": "12345", "caseDate": "3/22/21, 5:48:18 PM"]]`

Ideally I need it in plaintext more like

"3/22/21, 5:48:18 PM : 12345"

Any advice or help on the conversion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way if there is not a huge amount of data returned is to create a string from the fetched data and then write that string to disk

First create the string by getting the values from the dictionary and adding them in the right order into a string and joining the strings with a new line character

```
let output = results.reduce(into: []) { $0.append("\($1["caseDate", default: ""]) : \($1["caseNumber", default: ""])") }
    .joined(separator: "\n")
```

Then we can write them to file, here I use the Document directory as the folder to save the file in

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let path = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("results.txt")

do {
    try String(output).write(to: path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
    print("Failed to write to file, error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough, this worked perfectly. The only thing I had to update was the "results" call in the output declaration to "resultsDict" but other than that, flawless. Resolved two weeks worth of researching for me, and gave me a bit of insight into what I need to focus on next in my learning. Thanks again!